# How to properly change Child view's (@State/@Binding) variable from ParentView via function? (not in constructor)

Tags: swiftui

I want to achieve something similar to below;

```swift
struct PlaygroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Child()
                .myTapGesture {
                    print("outer gesture")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct Child: View {

    @State private var myTapGesture: () -> Void = { print("inner gesture") }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Child")
        .onTapGesture(perform: myTapGesture)
    }

    func myTapGesture(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Child {
        self.myTapGesture = action
        return self
    }

}
```

The main reason for my purpose is not to have a crowded init.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
struct Child: View {

    private var myTapGesture: () -> Void = { print("inner gesture") }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Child")
            .onTapGesture(perform: myTapGesture)
    }

    func myTapGesture(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> Child {
        var myCopy = self
        myCopy.myTapGesture = action
        return myCopy
    }
}
```

Update: added demo (Xcode 11.4)

[image: demo]

Comment: @EnesKaraosman, tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 with your `PlaygroundView`. How do you use it?

Comment: I found what I missed, I was marking `myTapGesture` with `@State`

Answer (score 0):

There's already a way to update SwiftUI `View`s with modifiers. Have a look at this:

```
struct TapViewModifier: ViewModifier {

    var onTapGesture: () -> Void = { print("default implementation here") }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onTapGesture(perform: onTapGesture)
    }
}
```

And the usage is:

```
struct PlaygroundView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Child()
                .modifier(TapViewModifier(onTapGesture: { print("your new implementation") }))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `Content` in modifier is a `View` (not a `Child` View), I cannot access/set my variables in it. (`onTapGesture` just was an example to simplify my question)

Answer (score 0):

If the child has a `@Binding` which it receives from the parent. Then it automatically updates when the parents `@State` updates. See e.g.

```
struct Parent: View {

    @State var myVar = 1

    var body: some View {
        Child(myVar: self.$binding)
    }

    func updated() { //when calling this function the @Binding in Child will also update
      self.myVar = 2
    }
}


struct Child: View {

    @Binding var myVar: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.myVar)
    }
}
```